# D3.js mouseovers on html5 canvas scatter plot

Tags: html, canvas, d3.js, scatter

Let's say we draw our scatter plot not with SVG but with canvas.

So something like:

```
    var scale = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    // Redraw axes
    x.domain([0, scale]);
    y.domain([0, scale]);
    xg.call(xAxis);
    yg.call(yAxis);

    var points = randomPoints(scale),
        colors = {};

    // Update canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    picker.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    points.forEach(function(p,i){

      // Space out the colors a bit
      var color = getColor(i * 1000 + 1);
      colors[color] = p;
      picker.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color + ")";

      context.beginPath();
      picker.beginPath();

      context.arc(x(p[0]), y(p[1]), 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      picker.arc(x(p[0]), y(p[1]), 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

      context.fill();
      picker.fill();

    });
```

Now how would we pass data into a mouseover event, say, to draw a tooltip?

The examples I've seen for tooltips all take for granted that you are handling an event with data bound to an element moused-over.

But what about for canvas?

I assume you'll need to use `d3.bisector` or something similar based on the x y coordinates of the mouse event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a solution suggested by Noah Veltman, as follows:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + " " + margin.top + ")");

var factory = d3.geom.quadtree()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ]);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var xg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

var yg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis");

var chartArea = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .style("left", margin.left + "px")
  .style("top", margin.top + "px");

var canvas = chartArea.append("canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#f0f";

// Layer on top of canvas, example of selection details
var highlight = chartArea.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
    .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .classed("hidden", true);

redraw();

function redraw() {

  // Randomize the scale
  var scale = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  // Redraw axes
  x.domain([0, scale]);
  y.domain([0, scale]);
  xg.call(xAxis);
  yg.call(yAxis);

  var points = randomPoints(scale);

  var tree = factory(points);

  // Update canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  points.forEach(function(p,i){

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x(p[0]), y(p[1]), 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();

  });

  canvas.on("mousemove",function(){

    var mouse = d3.mouse(this),
        closest = tree.find([x.invert(mouse[0]), y.invert(mouse[1])]);

    highlight.attr("cx", x(closest[0]))
      .attr("cy", y(closest[1]));

  });

  canvas.on("mouseover",function(){
    highlight.classed("hidden", false);
  });

  canvas.on("mouseout",function(){
    highlight.classed("hidden", true);
  });

}

function randomPoints(scale) {

  // Get points
  return d3.range(1000).map(function(d){

    return [
      Math.random() * scale,
      Math.random() * scale
    ];

  });

}
```

The key is the use of

`var factory = d3.geom.quadtree()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ]);`

Which has a getter setter function based on the x, y value pair of each point.

Comment: Original post and demo from Noah Veltman - for reference https://bl.ocks.org/veltman/1b43f61887e89c371f1c8c73341540a3

Comment: Note that the signature of quadtree.find() has changed in d3 v4. If you copy the code above, make the correction otherwise find() will return undefined.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to iterate trough all the points and check if the x and y matches the vicinity of the click. This will definitely be slow when the scatter chart points are too many.{I think in your case you are making scatter chart in canvas just to over come that issue}

Other way is to make the use of quad tree.
First I am making some random 10000 points.

```
  sampleData = d3.range(1000).map(function(d) {
    var datapoint = {};
    datapoint.id = "Sample Node " + d;
    datapoint.x = Math.random() * 500;
    datapoint.y = Math.random() * 500;

    return datapoint;
  })
```

Store all the points in the scatter chart in quad tree like this.

```
  quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()
    .extent([[0,0], [500,500]]) //here 500 is the width and height of the canvas or the max x/y range of the points in scatter chart.
    .x(function(d) {return d.x})
    .y(function(d) {return d.y});
```

Pass all the points into quadtree:

```
  quadData = quadtree(sampleData);
```

Now on click find the associated node data:

```
  quadData = quadtree(sampleData);
   d3.select("canvas").on("click", function(){
    found = []; 
    //find in the vicinity of 10 pixel around the click.
    search(quadData, d3.event.pageX -10, d3.event.pageY-10, d3.event.pageX +10, d3.event.pageY+10);
    var message = "";
    //iterate the found and make the message
    found.forEach(function(d){
      message += d.id + " ";
    });
    alert("selected Node" + message);
    var data
  })
```

Finally my search function to check for the nodes in the quadtree rectangle:

```
function search(quadtree, x0, y0, x3, y3) {
  quadtree.visit(function(node, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var p = node.point;
    if (p) {
      p.selected = (p.x >= x0) && (p.x < x3) && (p.y >= y0) && (p.y < y3);
      if(p.selected){
        found.push(p);
      }
    }
    return x1 >= x3 || y1 >= y3 || x2 < x0 || y2 < y0;
  });
}
```

Click on any of the circle and you will be alerted with the data it holds
working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AowXaSYsJM8NSH6IK5B7?p=preview)

Comment: I ended up using a similar solution, posted below.

Comment: yep moving with quadtree is the best solution in this case.

Comment: Yes. Note that there is a native `.find` method that saves you from having to write the search function.

Comment: yes you are right but the find will always return you one result.
What in the case if the points over lap that was the reason why i wrote the search. May be in your case the points don't overlap in that case find is definitely the best way forward.